# Query single server in SQL server group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 databases hosted across 3 different servers, all of which have different data and structures. I need to perform a query that will draw data from various tables across all three of them.

I've registered the three servers into a server group, and I've confirmed that all of the connections are working properly.

Here's an example of the problem I'm facing. For the first part of this query, I need to retrieve a list of records from the 'Applications' table in DB1 so I write:

```
SELECT * FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Application]
```

I know that this query works partially because it starts returning results from the correct table. The problem is that I haven't specified the server that DB1 is on, so once the query has finished querying DB1.dbo.Application, it looks for the same database and table on the next server. The database and table don't exist on the other servers so the query fails.

So how do I specify the server that I want the query to run on? I've tried `[server_name].[DB1].[dbo].[Application]`, but it still runs the query across all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server groups are for maintenance purposes, what you need to use is a [linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

On one of the servers, say `SERVER1`, you will need to set up two linked servers - one to `SERVER2` and one to `SERVER3`

From `SERVER1` you will then be able to query the other servers using the four part name in a normal query window:

```
SELECT * FROM DatabaseName.dbo.Table1;
SELECT * FROM SERVER2.DatabaseName.dbo.Table2;
SELECT * FROM SERVER3.DatabaseName.dbo.Table3;
```

You can also use the tables from the remote server in JOINs etc as though they were on the local server and the remote servers don't even need to run SQL Server - they can be Oracle, MYSQL etc.

Be aware though, [remote servers are slow](https://thomaslarock.com/2013/05/top-3-performance-killers-for-linked-server-queries/) and you may struggle with large datasets

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Worked like a charm.